# Product Qty instead Salable Qty

Tags: magento2.4, qty

How can i call Product Qty instead Salable Qty in

```
            if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $StockState = $objectManager->create('Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku');
                $qty = $StockState->execute($product->getSku());
                $product->setData('salable_qty', $qty[0]['qty']);
            }
```

i have deactivate Salable Qty in the trying to decrease product qty when the order is placed and not when it is shipped

Answer (score 0):

Try just

```
$product()->getQty();
```